# ER diagram to Postgres SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, erd

n real,
ProductID integer ,
PRIMARY KEY ()
)

Answer (score 1):

Would suggest you to go through what each of the notations/ symbols in an ER diagram literally means. It would be then easy for you to proceed further.

ER diagram mentioned by you is bit high level and not so deeper. So it should be easy for you if you learn up the notations.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).